# JQuery in content page not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, master-pages

I have been trying to make jquery datepicker plugin work on a content page but have been unable to make the page execute any jquery at all.  I managed to get the datepicker working on my masterpage but not the content page.  Also the firebug tool for firefox didnt pick up any javascript errors.  If anyone has a solution for making the datepicker work on my content page that would be great.  Thanks in advance.

.ASPX:

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#TextBoxConnectedOn").datepicker();
    });
  </script>
</asp:Content> 

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
  <input type="text" name="TextBoxConnectedOn" id="TextBoxConnectedOn" 
  runat="server" MaxLength="10"/>  
</asp:Content>
```

Masterpage head:

```
<head runat="server">
  <link type="text/css" href="pages/scripts/themes/ui-darkness/jquery.ui.all.css"
  rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/ui/jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js"></script>
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
  </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

EDIT
 I changed "#TextBoxConnectedOn" to "#<%= TextBoxConnectedOn.ClientID %>" and now firebug shows that its loading the needed pictures once i click on the input but still it doesnt show the datepicker.  My question topic and main source of frustration was the jquery not executing though so I suppose this post is answered,  thanks for all the info,  Ill see if i can find out why it doesnt display

Comment: Are all your JavaScript includes being loaded? You can check the firebug 'net' tab.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have double Ids of that TextBoxConnectedOn ?

Comment: @marto All of them are being loaded, thanks for the tip I didnt know firebug can show me that.

Comment: Is the content dynamically loaded, after the master page? i.e. if the master page loads and runs the `$("#TextBoxConnectedOn").datepicker();`, has the textbox with `id="TextBoxConnectedOn"` been loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a server-generated control the `id` of the input box won't actually be `TextBoxConnectedOn`; ASP.NET will have generated an `id` for you. View the source of the page in your browser to verify this.

You have two choices:

1. Remove the `runat="server"` attribute from the control, to make it a regular HTML element (does it really need to be server generated?), or
2. Reference the correct `id`

Like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#<%= TextBoxConnectedOn.ClientID %>").datepicker();
   });
 </script>
```

---

**EDIT**

As per @jbn's comment below, as of ASP.NET 4 you can tell server controls to use static IDs by setting their `ClientIDMode` to `Static`.

Comment: To do this, you need use CliendID control property:
`<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('<%="#"+TextBoxConnectedOn.ClientID%>').datepicker();
    });
  </script>
`

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ill google a bit to see if I can get the correct id then.

Comment: Sorry, that was in there but markdown screwed up my formatting :)

Comment: Ok, i checked firebug again and even though its not showing up, it is loading the needed pictures once i click on the input now.

Comment: I advise you put the javascript after body content. So you be sure the control is rended before you declare the script.

Comment: also, in asp.net 4, you can set the id to be static, so that in javascript the same id (without any prefixes) is available.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem before, where jQuery was being loaded on the master page, and then also the content page, this caused the jQuery on the content page to not work, so check the .net tab in firebug and make sure that jQuery is only being loaded once.

Hope this helps

Comment: It only shows once in firebug so I think that its only loading once, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src='<%=Url.Content("~/scripts/ui/jquery.ui.core.min.js")%>'></script>
```

This is usually a result of the js file not loading because of how the routing works. Try using the Url.Content() method as shown above.

Comment: Firebug shows all of them is being loaded thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Thats because your content page changes the id of your `input type="text"`.

Two methods to overcome this.

(a) Give a class to input type and call it using that.

```
<input type="text" name="TextBoxConnectedOn" id="TextBoxConnectedOn" 
  runat="server" MaxLength="10" class="mypicker/>
```

Now call it like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".mypicker").datepicker();
});
```

(b) Make the HTMLControl an ASP.NET Control and set `ClientIDMode="static"`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxConnectedOn"  runat="server" 
        ClientIDMode="Static"
        Width="240">
</asp:TextBox>
```

Then there is no need to change your script.